# I'm trying to find how to use response of event_search

Tags: api, eventbrite

```
eb.event_search(options, function (response) {
  alert(response.size);
```

This is the main point of mine.

Hmm actually I already know what fields are the event_search has.

But.. the problem is I can't use it at all.

Here is the link.

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/#

There are a lot of feilds but whatever I do.
I can't use it.

such as
      alert(response.num_showing);

```
  alert(response.total_items);

  alert(response.events.summary.num_showing);

  alert(response.events_summar_num_showing);

  alert(response.evnts_summary.num_showing);
```

But I got nothing.

Please let me know how to use them.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd `console.log(response);` to see what you have.

You should also be able to get a preview of the object structure by using the 'Try it Now' button on the event_search API documentation page.

Comment: Yeah I already tried but it's too narrow to use.
I saw all of the fields by that but the thing is... I DON'T KNOW how to pull and use.
When I looked at that, there are many kinds of ID.
for url ID
for real db ID
for ticket
and for venue ID
how can I use it? like event.id?
otherwise then how...? thanks all your time

Comment: Mr! Mr! I figured out! It was supposed to be "alert(response.events.length);" Thank you so much for your time!
the next one is that... kk how to use the fields. anyhow I'll find out
thx again!